# cannot run compiled typescript prog using module resolution

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I'm trying to compule the following typscript file

```
import { magic } from 'lib/magic';

magic();
```

The filestructure is:

```
./src/
     main.ts
     lib/
         a/magic.ts
         b/magic.ts
```

Inside tsconfig.json I map `lib/magic` to the right file as follows

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "lib/*": [ "src/lib/a/*" ]
        }
    },
    "include": [ "./src/**/*.ts" ],
    "exclude": [ "./node_modules" ]
}
```

It is that `paths` section that maps that import `lib/magic` to `./src/lib/a/magic.ts`.

So, I can compile as follows

```
$> tsc -p ./tsconfig-a.json
```

It produces output in `dist`. However, when I try to run it

```
$> node ./dist/main.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
    throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'lib/magic'
Require stack:
...
```

It makes sense, because in dist there is no such thing as `lib/magic`. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Until someone proves me wrong, here are my findings so far.

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866) is an issue in which it is stated that all this is in fact expected behaviour.

So you basically have to fix it in a second step. In my case I want to make 2 build, one for `a` and one for `b`. The easiest way to fix it then is to have it working by default for `a` as follows

```
import { magic } from './lib/a/magic';

magic();
```

Then build `b` and replace that path as follows

```
sed -e 's/lib\/a/lib\/b/' ./dist/main.js > ./dist/main-node.js
```

In my case, one version was for NodeJs and the other for the browser, so I also needed to add the `.js` extension. Just in case anyone is interested, here is the command

```
$> echo "import { magic } from  './lib/a/magic';" | sed "s#^\(import[^']*\)'\([^']*\)#\1 '\2.js#g"
```

Please let me know if you have a better solution, because all this feels a bit hacky